# Как спарсить все ссылки с sitemap.xml? Python

Tags: python, xml, xmlparser, sitemap

Есть карта сайта:
https://www.stussy.com/sitemap_products_1.xml?from=4103557054560&to=6660699586656
Мне нужно спарсить все ссылки на товары. Каким способом лучше сделать?

Comment: Так в метках вопроса фактически полный ответ есть: python, xml, xmlparser... Что-то конкретное не получается?

Comment: Возможно ли как то получить xml разметку с запроса? Когда я впервые столкнулся с картой сайта, я сделал запрос на неё и парсил по html коду xml файл.

Comment: Да, sitemap и есть самый обычный XML, и работать с ним нужно как с обычным XML. Что конкретно вызывает трудности, где код с проблемами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо просто явно указать тип документа:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.stussy.com/sitemap_products_1.xml?from=4103557054560&to=6660699586656'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "xml")
loc_list = soup.find_all('loc')

for loc in loc_list:
    print(f"{loc.text}")
```